# IO streams to JPanel, GUI with InputStream and OutputStream in a JPanels JTextField and JTextArea

Tags: user-interface, inputstream, jtextfield, jtextarea, outputstream

I'm trying to write a GUI where the user sees the System output in a JTextArea and where he writes the input in a JTextField, both object inside a JPanel.
How do I do to connect the System output stream to the JTextArea and the System input stream to the JTextField? I have googled and searched these forums but havnt found the solution. I would be very happy if someone could help me with this.

I have a Master class that calls the JPanel with the GUI, and I will have work executed in different threads later on, but right now I struggle with the basic issue of connecting IO streams to the JPanel. Down below is the 2 classes:

```
public class MainTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    JPanelOUT testpanel = new JPanelOUT();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(testpanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();

    /*
    System.setOut(CONVERT TEXTAREA TO AN OUTPUTSTREAM SOMEHOW??(JPanelOUT.textArea)));

    System.setIn(CONVERT STRING TO AN INPUTSTREAM SOMEHOW?? JPanelOUT.textField);
    */
    String text = Sreadinput();
    System.out.println(text);   
}

public static String Sreadinput() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(JPanelOUT.is));
    String input=in.readLine();
    return input;
}
```

}

```
public class JPanelOUT extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
protected static JTextField textField;
protected static JTextArea textArea;
public static InputStream is;
private final static String newline = "\n";

public JPanelOUT() throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException {
    super(new GridBagLayout());

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("OUTPUT:");;
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("INPUT:");;

    textField = new JTextField(20);
    textField.addActionListener(this);
    textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setBackground(Color.black);
    textArea.setForeground(Color.white);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,200));

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    add(label1, c);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    add(scrollPane, c);
    c.weightx = 0;
    c.weighty = 0;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    add(label2, c);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    add(textField, c);

    String WelcomeText1 = "Hello and welcome to the TEST";
    String WelcomeText2 = "Trying to get the input field below to become the System.in and this output";
    String WelcomeText3 = "field to become the System.out (preferrably both with UTF-8 encoding where";
    String WelcomeText4 = "the scrollpane automatically scrolls down to the last output line)!";
    textArea.append(WelcomeText1 + newline + newline + WelcomeText2 + newline + WelcomeText3 + newline + WelcomeText4 + newline + newline);

    String text = textField.getText();
    is =new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String text2 = textField.getText();

    textArea.append(text2 + newline);
    textField.selectAll();
    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
}
```

}

Comment: OK, after working with it for 5 hours I solved it, but the solution is not as slick as I want it. I cant really redirect the inputstream, but instead I use a while loop to catch a string which goes on forever until it is set by the actionevent to be non null.
If anyone has a more direct solution to this issue I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: And I suspect that there is a good reason why redirecting the inputstream is not easy... Passing commands to the system is not a great gift to give to malicious users...

Answer (score 0):

i am new to java, trying to deal with the streams, too :)
Sorry for bad English I am from Russia.
May be this code will help you.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form NewJFrame
 */
public MyPrintStream myPrintStream;
public NewJFrame()throws FileNotFoundException{
    initComponents();
    this.myPrintStream = new MyPrintStream("string");
}
private class MyPrintStream extends PrintStream {        
    MyPrintStream(String str)throws FileNotFoundException{
        super(str);
    }
    public void println(String s){
        textArea1.append(s+'\n');
    }
} .. continuation class code
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel... */

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            try{
            NewJFrame myJFrame = new NewJFrame();
            myJFrame.setVisible(true);                    
            System.setOut(myJFrame.myPrintStream);
            System.out.println("its work");
            System.out.println("its work2");
            System.out.print("str"); //does not work, need to override
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){System.out.println (e.getMessage());}
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer user2443955, I will look into what you wrote after I solve some other problems that has popped up with applets-servlet-server programming...